# How to detect if the flutter app is running on Google Play Pre-Launch report devices?

Tags: flutter, google-play-console

With Java / Kotlin, you can detect when the app is being launched by the Pre-Launch service:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/android-studio#modify_instrumented_test_behavior_for

How do we do this using flutter/dart?

Activities from these devices are "polluting" my analytics. It's minor, but it would be nice to know when they are running so I can disable the analytics.

Comment: You can create a flutter to native channel and get to know if launched by the Pre-Launch service. With the same native code. [Method channel](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=type-mappings-swift-tab#example-client)

Comment: There is a plugin that does exactly that: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_runtime_env